# problems when using pip for python

Tags: python, installation, pip, xlsxwriter

I've managed to install xlsxwriter using my cmd as I need to use it for my python progect but after the module having installed and the cmd having returned "successfully installed xlsxwriter" it doesn't seem to have worked.
when I go to the python shell to import xlsxwriter it returns no moduel named xlsxwriter.

p.s. the command I typed into the cmd was c:\python34\script\pip install xlsxwriter
p.p.s im using windows 10 and python 3.5.1

Comment: I think the answer is in the question: You installed it with `pip` for python 3.4, and are running python 3.5.1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> p.s. the command I typed into the cmd was c:\python34\script\pip install xlsxwriter p.p.s im using windows 10 and python 3.5.1

Is it possible that you installed it for your python 3.4 installation and are trying to use it with your python 3.5 installation?

Please try `where python` to see which python installation is your default (i.e. is listed first in your PATH).

I would assume you need to

```
C:\python35\scripts\pip install xlsxwriter
C:\python35\python.exe
```

or add the version you want to default to to your PATH environment variable.

Have a look at  the python documentation [parts regarding windows installs and environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables).